# jQuery - Change values when checkboxes are checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

i have three checkboxes in HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="a2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="a3" />
<span class="price"></span>
```

I want to do this: 
If id A1 is checked, change text in span to priceUp.
If ids A1 and A2 is checked, change text in span to priceDown.
If ids A1,A2 and A3 is checked, change text in span to priceNormal.

Comment: That's nice.  Have you tried anything?  We're not going to do this for you.  We'll help if you get stuck, but we're not gonna do it for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#a1 ,#a2 , #a3').on('click' , function(){
    var $a1Check  = $('#a1').is(':checked');
    var $a2Check  = $('#a2').is(':checked');
    var $a3Check  = $('#a3').is(':checked');
    var text = '' ;
    if( $a1Check && $a2Check && $a3Check){
        text = 'priceNormal';
    }
    else if($a1Check && $a2Check){
          text = 'priceDown';
    }    
    else if($a1Check)  {
        text = 'priceUp';
    }        

    $('.price').html(text);
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/UNhNc/)**

Comment: @Peter ... Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 4):

With jQuery you can listen on "change" for the element you want to watch.

This could look like this (e.g. only for id "a1"):

```
$("#a1").change( function() {
  if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
    // do something if a1 is checked
  } else if ( $(this).not(":checked") ) {
    // do something if a1 is unchecked
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can see if your checkbox is checked.

```
$('#a1').click (function ()
{
    var thisCheck = $(this);
    if (thischeck.is (':checked'))
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```